# The image processing fails when blue color is in the frame. What might be the reason?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a project that is about lane detection on a green path. The pipeline involves this pipeline:

- Denoise --> BGR2HSV --> HSV Filter --> Canny Edge Detection --> Crop to ROI --> Hough Line Detection --> Process lines

The whole flow works as expected most of the time on a real time Raspberry Pi camera. However, if there is an occurrence of blue color in the camera frame, the capture gets blurred gradually (see the GIF link) and lastly, execution stops by raising "Floating point exception". Until now, I couldn't understand the reason behind it, because it is specific to blue color. What I tried is I just disabled line process algorithm and finished the pipeline at Hough line detector. Just observed the the pipeline effect. The blurring kept happening but "Floating point exception" did not raise. Moreover, I tried processing in my Ubuntu 18.04 but on a already recorded video. The blue color didn't cause any problem when I observed the process frame by frame.

Could you help me to point out the problem? I hope I could tell it clearly.

GDB Output:  received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception. __GI_raise (sig=) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: NO such file or directory.

p.s. I use OpenCV 4.0 in C++.

[The explanatory GIF](https://giphy.com/gifs/1o1uCG8YvXIwqA89Fh)

The original image looks like this:
[image: [1]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWhk8.png).

The distorted image after blue object in the frame: [image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S7F7.png)

HSV Filter parameters for green color:

- H[62,90], S[148,255], V[131,206]

Code snippet:

```
while (true) {

        timeCapture = (double) cv::getTickCount(); // capture the starting time

        cap >> frame_orig;

        if (frame_counter != 2){
            frame_counter++;
            }
        else {
            frame_counter = 0;
        // check if the input video can be opened
        if (frame_orig.empty()) {
            std::cout << "!!! Input video could not be opened" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        avgCounter++; // increment the process counter
        frameHeight = frame_orig.rows;
        frameWidth = frame_orig.cols;

        // denoise the frame using a Gaussian filter
        img_denoise = lanedetector.deNoise(frame_orig);

        // convert from BGR to HSV colorspace
        cv::cvtColor(img_denoise, frame_HSV, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);

        // apply color thresholding HSV range for green color
        cv::inRange(frame_HSV, cv::Scalar(low_H, low_S, low_V),
                cv::Scalar(high_H, high_S, high_V), frame_threshed);

        // canny edge detection to the color thresholded image
        // (50,200,3)
        Canny(frame_threshed, frame_cannied, 133, 400, 5, true);

        // copy cannied image
        cv::cvtColor(frame_cannied, frame_houghP, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

//      std::ofstream myfile;
//      myfile.open("test.txt", std::ios_base::app);

        frame_masked = lanedetector.cropROI(frame_cannied);
        // runs the line detection
        std::vector<cv::Vec4i> line;
        HoughLinesP(frame_masked, lines_houghP, 1, CV_PI / 180, threshold,
                (double) maxLineGap, (double) minLineLength);
        if (!lines_houghP.empty()) {
            // sort the found lines from smallest y to largest y coordinate
            quickSort(lines_houghP, 0, lines_houghP.size());
            // reverse the order largest y to smallest y coordinate
            reverseVector(lines_houghP);

            // Separate lines into left and right lines
            left_right_lines = lanedetector.lineSeparation(lines_houghP,
                    frame_masked);

            // Apply regression to obtain only one line for each side of the lane
            lane = lanedetector.regression(left_right_lines, frame_threshed);

            // Plot lane detection
            flag_plot = lanedetector.plotLane(frame_orig, lane);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < lines_houghP.size(); i++) {
            cv::Vec4i l = lines_houghP[i];
            if (red < 0)
                red = 155;
            if (green < 0)
                green = 55;
            cv::line(frame_houghP, cv::Point(l[0], l[1]), cv::Point(l[2], l[3]),
                    cv::Scalar(255, green, red), 3, cv::LINE_AA);
            red = red - 20;
            green = green - 20;
        }
        }
        //  std::cout << "xTrainData (python)  = " << std::endl << format(frame_houghP, Formatter::FMT_PYTHON) << std::endl << std::endl;

        // calculate the process time
        timeCapture = ((double) cv::getTickCount() - timeCapture)
                / cv::getTickFrequency() * 1000;
        if (avgCounter == fps) {
            std::cout
                    << "The average process time for each 30 frames in milliseconds:     "
                    << (avgRunTime / fps) << std::endl;
            avgCounter = 0;
            avgRunTime = 0;
        } else
            avgRunTime += timeCapture;

        //imshow(window_capture_name, frame_orig);
        imshow(window_lane_detected, frame_houghP);
        imshow(winodw_hsv_filtered, frame_threshed);
        imshow(window_canny_applied, frame_cannied);
        imshow(window_masked, frame_masked);
        imshow(window_vision, frame_orig);

        if (!writer.isOpened()) {
            std::cout << "Could not open the output video file for write\n";
            return -1;
        }
        writer.write(frame_orig);
        red = 250;
        green = 250;

        char key = (char) cv::waitKey(30);
        if (key == 'q' || key == 27) {
            break;
        }

        std::cin.get();
            }


    }
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the color detection algorithm so that HSV does not come into play? There does not seem to be anything special in the color blue.

Comment: Are certain about the color component ordering in the input images coming from the camera? If it’s specific to the color blue, I would immediately suspect a mismatch with the color components or their bitwise representation

Comment: @LSerni, I preferred HSV filter to have robust processing in changing lighting conditions. Do you have a recommendation? I actually need to find edges of the lane. So before Canny, I should filter out the color I guess.

Comment: @alterigel ,  I don't think I have control over RGB bit values of the camera? Or did I get you wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The image processing fails in blue color. What might be the reason?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55317159/the-image-processing-fails-in-blue-color-what-might-be-the-reason)

Comment: @beaker You are right. But I propose to close the other question since this one is later and more detailed (actually, etpc, you might consider deleting the old question yourself).

Comment: @etpc I was proposing to shut off the HSV part to see if there was any problem there. Or better, save the frame in HSV from both a green and a blue scene, and see whether anything appears off in the two HSV frames. I concur with alter igel that the low-level representation might contain some anomaly.

Comment: @beaker thank you for the warning, I deleted the duplicate question.

Comment: @LSerni, that sounds good, thank you for the recommendation. I am gonna check that and update with the news.

Comment: @LSerni , I disabled HSV filtering (still converted BGR2HSV), the rest of the pipeline worked under blue color. Then I disabled pipeline after HSV filter, the image is distorted in this case. I guess you and alter igel is right. Actually, I don't know how to proceed from this point on. How can I effect or correct the low level representation?

Comment: Any help from the community is appreciated. I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my question, as I see the problem is related with the Raspberry Pi camera. It wasn't a genuine Pi camera, a clone. When there is a blue object in the frame, the pixel values are changing as @alterigel pointed out. After running several tests to asses if it was a software error, I concluded that it is related with camera hardware itself.